# Isekai where a person gets sent to another world forest with a shotgun

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I don't remember much about it but there were elves in the story I think. Just basically he gets sent to another world with a shotgun.

I can confirm that it is not any of the following:

- *[When a Gun Nerd Is Reincarnated to a World of Magic, He Established a Harem army with Modern Weapons!?](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=123074)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be *[An Active Hunter in Hokkaido Has Been Thrown Into a Different World](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=156697)*...?

It definitely has elves in it (named as such in the story), and after being attacked by a bear, the male protagonist suddenly finds himself in a forest in another world, armed with nothing but his shotgun.

[image]

Description:

> In modern Hokkaido a brown bear has appeared near an elementary school, so a member of the local hunters' association is dispatched to exterminate it. However he gets killed by the bear and wakes up in a fantasy world, armed with only the Remington M870 shotgun he had when he died.

Comment: thank you so much.